# Matrix Trackpad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, capacitive, matrix

I wanted to build a matrix capacitive trackpad. Ideally, its PCB would have 4 layers:

1--> The plate array
2--> The circuit that links the rows (horizontally)
3--> The circuit that links the column (vertically)
4--> the ground

There is a way to do it with 2 layers? In a way that the 2 3 4 layers are placed in the same layer.
Can anyone provide some related papers or projects?

Comment: Just use 4 layers?